# How do I deal with namespaces in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am new to XSL and would like to transform a NewML G2 format XML into another XML.

For example I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- 
- Structure: NML2 SNI Text 
-->
<!-- ========================================================= -->
<newsMessage xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/" xmlns:rtr="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <header>
    <transmitId>tag:123.com,0000:newsml_N19279043:609406403</transmitId>
    <priority>3</priority>
    <destination>ABX</destination>
  </header>
  <itemSet>
    <newsItem conformance="power" guid="tag:reuters.com,0000:newsml_N19279043" standard="NewsML-G2" standardversion="2.1" version="609406403" xml:lang="en">
      <itemMeta>
        <itemClass qcode="icls:text" rtr:msgType="S"/>
        <provider literal="reuters.com"/>
        <versionCreated>2011-05-20T05:00:27.000Z</versionCreated>
      </itemMeta>
      <contentMeta>
        <urgency>3</urgency>
        <infoSource literal="Reuters" role="cRole:origProv"/>
        <subject qcode="N2:BNK"/>
        <headline>My Headline</headline>
        <by>ABC</by>
      </contentMeta>
      <contentSet>
        <inlineXML contenttype="application/xhtml+html" wordcount="881">
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
              <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
              <p>Paragraph A</p>
              <p>* Paragraph A</p>
            </body>
          </html>
        </inlineXML>
      </contentSet>
    </newsItem>
  </itemSet>
</newsMessage>
```

I would like my result XML to be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyData>
        <MyTransmitId>tag:123.com,0000:newsml_N19279043:609406403</MyTransmitId>
        <MyHeadline>My Headline</MyHeadline>
        <MyContent>
          <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
              <title/>
            </head>
            <body>
              <p>Paragraph A</p>
              <p>* Paragraph A</p>
            </body>
          </html>
        </MyContent>
</MyData>
```

I come out with the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/newsMessage">
    <MyTransmitId>
      <xsl:value-of select="header/transmitId"/>
        </MyTransmitId>
    <MyHeadline>
      <xsl:value-of select="itemSet/newsItem/contentMeta/headline"/>
    </MyHeadline>
    <MyContent>
      <xsl:value-of select="itemSet/newsItem/contentSet/inlineXML"/>
    </MyContent>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However it transforms to something not quite right. And I noticed it is because of the element

```
<newsMessage xmlns="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/" xmlns:rtr="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

If I change it to the below then my XSL will work:

```
<newsMessage>
```

How do I transform the element newsMessage with the namespaces properly?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I edited the title to make it a little more search-friendly.  If you prefer the old one, feel free to roll back the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of problems here:

First, much of your source document is in the Namespace named "http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/", and you need to take this into account when referencing that content in your XSLT. In the stylesheet below I have done that by binding this Namespace to the prefix "itpc", and then using that in the XPath expressions.

Secondly, you want the XHTML content structure to be copied into your result, and you need to use <xsl:copy-of> (not value-of) to do that — in fact you need to get the *content* of your inlineXML element, rather than it itself; I have modified the XPath accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:itpc="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="/itpc:newsMessage">
        <MyTransmitId>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="itpc:header/itpc:transmitId"/>
        </MyTransmitId>
        <MyHeadline>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="itpc:itemSet/itpc:newsItem/itpc:contentMeta/itpc:headline"/>
        </MyHeadline>
        <MyContent>
            <xsl:copy-of
                select="itpc:itemSet/itpc:newsItem/itpc:contentSet/itpc:inlineXML/*"/>
        </MyContent>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want! You have provided me with not just answer but a lot of new information which now make sense to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Declare the namespace and use it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:nar="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/">
 ...
    <xsl:template match="/nar:newsMessage">
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks. That is declaring the 1st namespace, how do I specify the 2nd name space which is xmlns:rtr="http://www.reuters.com/ns/2003/08/content"? I tried with just one name space and I get the result: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyTransmitId xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:nar="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"></MyTransmitId>
<MyHeadline xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:nar="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"></MyHeadline>
<MyContent xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:nar="http://iptc.org/std/nar/2006-10-01/"></MyContent>

Comment: Declare them and use it like: <xsl:template match="/nar/rtm/x/xsi:newsMessage">?

Comment: I have no clue what that XPath expression is supposed to resolve to. You declare a namespace by adding another `xmlns` attribute. You use a namespace by putting the identifier and a colon before the tag or attribute in question.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this one, posting here for the benefits of others :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="MyData">
            <xsl:element name="MyTransmitId">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='transmitId']"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="MyHeadline">
                <xsl:value-of select="//*[name()='headline']"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="MyContent">
                <xsl:copy-of select="//*[name()='inlineXML']/*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Except that is a very fragile approach is it relies on the source document's Namespaces being recorded lexically the same way every time. If for some reason prefixes were used, the stylesheet would fail. You could guard against that by using local-name() rather than name()